# Check user authentication from "website a" on "website b"

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, facebook, authentication

I have a 'little' problem.

I am working on a project for school in Ruby on Rails: a platform where people can share things with eachother. I recently started working on widgets which people can place on their website.

In the widget you see this 'thing' and how much it is shared. But now when someone loads the widget I want to check if he is logged in on my website and then show him which friends of him/her also shared that thing. I've Been thinking and trying a few hours now but haven't figured something out yet.

I have tried to use the Facebook SDK but could not get it to work because this is domain limited. Altough Facebook would not have been the best option I think because then it is only available for people who have their Facebook account linked to their account on my website.

Probably I have to create something by my own. But I have no clue how to do it right now. I hope someone can point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 1):

If A and b are on the same domain as a subdomains you can use cookies to store authentication token and in that case that will work.

If not, you can use OAuth for example http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OAuth.
Ruby has a bunch of gems to support that. Devise has OAuth integration as well as authlogic.
Twitter uses that widely.

Also there are CAS and WebAUTH those do quite the same.

Answer (score 0):

You can list both domains (A and B) on application settings under Basic section in **App Domain** field. This will allow you to use Facebook JS-SDK on both sites with same application id.

You should understand that this will allow both sites to access personal info of your users and this should be done only if you have control on those sites since you are responsible for application who uses JS-SDK